# Free, web based alternative to Visio?

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, visio

I have used Visio to map out my network structure, and have used the export function to create an HTML page that is searchable by IP, hostname etc. This is a really nice tool and I use it often.

However, I would like for users who do not use Internet Explorer to be able to use the search features. What are some alternatives to Visio here? I want to draw a network diagram where objects are searchable.

Thanks!

Update:

I tried Oskar's suggestion by installing the Visio 2010 Beta. I was now able to save the Visio diagrams as SVGs, but the functionality is still not there.

Actually, Visio 2010 now won't export web pages where the search works properly even in VML or IE :( I sent a "frown" to MS about this but I doubt I'll hear back from them.

Comment: Does it work better in Visio 2010 perhaps? Microsoft seems to have shifted compatibility focus with all 2010 product lines - dropping IE6 support and adding Firefox and Safari instead...

Comment: what about exporting to a PDF? Searchable and usable for anybody with a PDF reader.

Comment: @MattB That could work, but what is nice about the Visio objects on a web page is that they contain more data. That way you don't have to have all the information as text on the page. 

E.g. you have a switch that has an IP, a hostname, a model number, etc. and this is the searchable switch "object". If there is a way to do this with a PDF I would like to know however :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try Gliffy: http://www.gliffy.com/

Comment: Gliffy does have a free version but it's pretty limited and only allows public diagrams ... it might be worth the small monthly fee to get the standard version at least.

Answer (score 1):

There are various online tools in addition to Gliffy mentioned capable of this. [draw.io](https://www.draw.io), [Cacoo](http://www.cacoo.com), [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com) and [Creately](http://www.creately.com) come to mind.

Comment: Just a heads-up that short posts like this to a specific product always look like spam. It's only seeing your other posts that stopped me flagging this one.

Comment: I was just looking at Lucidchart ... they have an function for importing visio diagrams, that might suit you well.